# Can Debian based distributions use .deb to install packages?

Tags: linux, debian, packages, dpkg

For example, I'm running sparky linux.  I'm wondering if I can install packages that are meant for debian distributions using dpkg -i on an *.deb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I previously left a comment based on possibly misreading your question, so I'll expand it here to clarify.

**Package Formats**

There are several different formats for packaging Linux software.  Everything in the Debian family tree uses .deb packaging.  So if you need to load a driver that is available in .deb, .rpm, and a tarball, the choice would be .deb.

However, as @Xen2050 describes, not everything that is packaged in a .deb  will necessarily be compatible with everything that differentiates Sparky from other distros in the Debian family.  The are two type of issues.

**Compatibility Issues**

Linux distros contain a large collection of components and not all of the components available for creating a distro play well with each other.  You can't build a distro by arbitrarily selecting from a "Chinese menu" of available pieces--one from column A and two from column B.  So the particular software in a given .deb may not be compatible with something in Sparky.  Generally speaking, things like applications software will usually work.  Things that modify the distro, itself, are often ify.

**Stability Issues**

The second issue is stability (the likelihood of having problems).  At their core, Debian-based distros are based on one of three levels of validation.

- The **Stable** version is like the Hanes lady ("It doesn't say Hanes until I say it says Hanes").  Everything is extensively tested and doesn't get into the distro until it is proven problem-free.
- Sparky is based on Debian **Testing**.  This contains stuff that is in the process of evaluation.  It hasn't yet either been sufficiently proven for inclusion in Stable or identified as having a serious problem.
- The third level is **Unstable**.  This is stuff that should theoretically be compatible and looks nice to evaluate for possible inclusion, but has not entered the testing process.

The testing process is as much about serious bugs in the software as compatibility with the core distro.  There is a trade-off.  If you want the latest and greatest release of some software, it probably won't come from a Stable repository.

**Source**

If you are getting your .deb package from a third party, it's "stability level" is unknown.  If you are getting it from a distro repository, the source will indicate this.  With Sparky, something you get from a Stable repository will be better tested than what is in Sparky, itself (although not necessarily compatible with Sparky).  Something you get from an Unstable repository will have unknown quality and could potentially introduce problems.

Answer (score 0):

Does your distribution have `dpkg` installed? Just typing it in a terminal should give you an answer. If you do, then you should be able to install .deb packages. And you may need some other dependent packages too. If there's an `apt-get` or software repository version to install that would probably be preferred.
(You can download your distro-specific .deb files, then later install them with `dpkg` too)

BUT, you should only install packages that are for your specific distro, preferably Sparky Linux, or it [looks like](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=sparky) it's based on Debian Testing, so from there.

You could *try* installing .deb packages from other distributions, but they may not work properly, or at all.